# Question about Euler equation and material derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

From the Euler equation
$$\partial_t\rho(x,t)+\partial_x(\rho(x,t) v(x,t))=0$$
we get the material derivative form;
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{dt}\rho=-\rho\partial_x v,
\end{equation}
where
$$\frac{d}{dt}=\partial_t+v(x,t)\partial_x$$
denotes the directional derivative along the direction
\begin{equation}
    \frac{dx}{dt}=v(x,t)
\end{equation}

for any point $(\bar{x},\bar{t})\in\mathbb{R}_+^2:={(x,t):x\in\mathbb{R},t\in\mathbb{R}_+},\mathbb{R}_+=(0,\infty)$, the integral curve of $\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x,t)$ through $(\bar{x},\bar{t})$ is denoted by $x=x(t;\bar{x},\bar{t})$.

At $t=0$, it passes through the point
$(x_0(\bar{x},\bar{t}),0):=(x(0;\bar{x},\bar{t}),0)$.

Along the curve $x=x(t;\bar{x},\bar{t})$, the solution of the ordinary differential equation with initial data:
$$\rho|_{t_0}=\rho_0(x_{0}(\bar{x},\bar{t}))$$
is
$$\rho(\bar{x},\bar{t})=\rho_0(x_0(\bar{x},\bar{t}))\exp\Big{(}-\int_0^{\bar{t}}\partial_xv(x(t;\bar{x},\bar{t}),t)dt\Big{)}>0$$

Here I have some questions;

first, clearly $\frac{dx}{dt}=\partial_tx+v(x.t)\partial_x x=v(x,t)$ hold, and the directional derivative along the direction $[1,v(x,t)]^T$ for scalar function $f=f(x,t)$ is
\begin{equation*}
    D_vf=Df(x,t) 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    v(x,t)
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_t f&\partial_x f
    \end{pmatrix}
     \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    v(x,t)
    \end{pmatrix}
    =\partial_t f+v(x,t)\partial_x f
\end{equation*}

In our paper, material derivative is interpreted as a directional derivative with respect to $v(x,t)$, but according to my calculations, it is considered to be exactly a directional derivative with respect to $[1\ \ v(x,t)]^T$. Is this thinking correct?

second,
for any point $(\bar{x},\bar{t})\in\mathbb{R}_+^2:={(x,t):x\in\mathbb{R},t\in\mathbb{R}_+},\mathbb{R}_+=(0,\infty)$, the integral curve of $\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x,t)$ through $(\bar{x},\bar{t})$ is denoted by $x=x(t;\bar{x},\bar{t})$.
Is there any equation which explicitly represent $x$ as function of$(t,\bar{x},\bar{t})$?

Third,
Here I'm not exactly sure what an integral curve is.
Along the curve $x=x(t;\bar{x},\bar{t})$, the solution of the ordinary differential equation $(\frac{d\rho}{dt}=-\rho\partial_x v)$ with initial data:
$$\rho|_{t_0}=\rho_0(x_{0}(\bar{x},\bar{t}))$$
is
$$\rho(\bar{x},\bar{t})=\rho_0(x_0(\bar{x},\bar{t}))\exp\Big{(}-\int_0^{\bar{t}}\partial_xv(x(t;\bar{x},\bar{t}),t)dt\Big{)}>0$$

Here I don't know why the solution for differential equation which is represented by material derivative is the function of $(\bar{x},\bar{t})$ rather than a function of $(x,t)$.

Answer (score 1):

To the last, the text seems to prefer to have $(\bar x,\bar t)$ as unchangeable points during the calculation, so that $t$ and $x$ are free as integration variable and flow function. You could shift that if, for example, you use $\tau$ for the integration variable and $\varphi$ for the flow function.

---

The rest seems ok, only I would order it or move the focus it differently. The primary data is $v$, from this vector field follows the flow $x$. Then the "material derivative" is just the time derivative along the flow lines/characteristic curves or integral (to the vector field) curves. This can indeed be seen as a directional derivative related to $v$.

Then along the characteristic curves the PDE reduces to an ODE, with the given solution formula.

---

Usually one would order the components of the Jacobian in the order of the arguments, that is, the tangent of the curve $[x(t),t]$ would be $[v(x(t),t),1]$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but a different approach. Consider this as a comment but too long to be edited in the comments section.
$$\partial_t\rho(x,t)+\partial_x(\rho(x,t) v(x,t))=0\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial \rho(x,t)}{\partial t}+v(x,t)\frac{\partial \rho(x,t)}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}\rho(x,t)$$
I suppose that $v(x,t)$ is a known function (a given function). If not the equation $(1)$ would involve two unknown functions $v(x,t)$ and $\rho(x,t)$ which would make it not solvable because only one equation for two unknowns.

$v=v(x,t)$ being a known function implies that $v_x=v_x(x,t)$ is a known function.

On condensed scripf :
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+v\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}=-v_x\rho$$
This is a first order linear PDE wrt the unknown function $\rho(x,t)$.

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{v}=\frac{d\rho}{-v_x}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{d\rho}{-v_x}$ :
$$\rho+\int v_x(x,t)dt=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{v}=\frac{d\rho}{-v_x}$ :
$$\rho+\ln|v|=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $F(c_1,c_2)=0$ is :
$$\boxed{F\left(\left(\rho+\int v_x(x,t)dt\right)\:,\:\big(\rho+\ln|v(x,t)|\big)\right)=0}$$
$F(X,Y)$ is an arbitrary function of two variables
where $\begin{cases}X=\rho+\int v_x(x,t)dt \\ Y=\rho+\ln|v(x,t)| \end{cases}$.

Without specifying some initial and/or boundary condition one cannot go further.

If an initial and/or boundary condition is given (or arbitrary chosen) one can expect to determine the function $F$ and find a solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.